# Can linear regressions be used, given these diagnostic plots?

Tags: regression, linear, model, diagnostic

I'm using several linear regressions on a big dataset (about 1000 datapoints) with one numerical dependent variable and several independent variables (both dummy and numerical): `lm(numerical1 ~ dummy1 + dummy2 + dummy3 + dummy4 + dummy5 + dummy6 + dummy7 + numerical2 + numerical3, data=mydata)`.

I've looked at diagnostic plots (see some below) but I do not manage to decide whether I can use linear regressions with my data. Interpreting diagnostic plots appears quite subjective to me. I know a more objective way is to check linear regression assumptions using statistical tests but this approach has been criticised as being too conservative.

Moreover, I've tried to log-transform the dependent variable for some regressions but the diagnostic plots do not look better with than without log-transformation (see an example below). Also, data transformation has been criticised by some statisticians.

My question is: **Can I use linear regressions, given these diagnostic plots?** If this is possible, I'd like not to do data transformation.

Thank you for any suggestion. I'm quite new to interpreting diagnostic plots.

***Here are the diagnostic plots of four of my linear regressions:*** [image: Plots]

***Here is the comparison between no transformation (left) vs. log-transformation (right) of the dependent variable:*** [image: Plots log]

Comment: What's the histogram of numerical2 or numerical3? Looks like at least one has a point mass, like in the case of lab data where a significant portion of the sample renders as "below lower limit of detection" and so the lab enters the lower limit as the value. The easiest approach is to impute LLD / 2 as the value in fact, but there are more sophisticated methods.

Comment: Hi, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnDAK.png) are the histograms of numerical2 and numerical3. I'm not sure if this applies?

Comment: Bizarre, the "straight line" that shows up is puzzling. Anyway, there's nothing we can say without knowing the data.

Comment: The large, large $n$ leads me not to be concerned at all about the robustness, statistical inference is not obviously affected by any of these diagnostic plots.  If prediction is the objective, this is a rudimentary model building and there are probably higher level effects, like interactions or splines for continuous predictors, that could be assessed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The objective is to test whether one (or several) indepedent variable affects the dependent variable and if yes, how.

Comment: @AdamO For this objective, if I've understood correctly, the diagnostic plots are okay (or good enough) and so I can use linear regressions with my data?

Comment: The diagnostic plots do not, in my mind, suggest any distributional problem with the data, although there is a clustering of data/collinearity in the first panel that deserves comment.

Comment: Actually, the dependent variable in the first model has several datapoints with value on the upper limit of the variable

Comment: Correct -- and that *could* be a problem.  But whether it is a problem depends on why you are doing these regressions.  That information is crucial for providing useful advice to you.

Comment: Yes, I forgot adding this important information. My goal is answering the question whether each of my independent variables have a statistically significant relationship with my dependent variable, and if yes, whether this relationship is a positive or negative relationship.